# Value error for multi-request processing

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting error message given below and the same organization of elements is working pretty fine in other programs. I tried many solutions but it seems not working.

```
html = browse.open(url).read()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 188, in open
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1062, in do_request_
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Following is the code....please advise.

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import readability
from readability.readability import Document
import re
import urlparse
import urllib
import json
import gzip

"""Functions"""
def translateString(homeLanguage, targetLanguage, transText):
    post_url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t"
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Firefox")]
# these are the paramaters you have got from the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'client':'t',
                  'text':transText,
                  'h1':homeLanguage,
                  's1':homeLanguage,
                  't1':targetLanguage,
                  'ie':'UTF-8',
                  'oe':'UTF-8',
                  'multires': '1',
                  'otf': '2',
                  'pc': '0',
                  'ssel':'0',
                  'tsel':'0'
                  }
#Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters) 
#submit the form (POST request). you get the post_url and the request type(POST/GET)     
#the same way with the parameters 
    trans_array = br.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8') 

#Submit the form (GET request)
    trans_string = ""
    sections = trans_array.split("]]")
    secarray = sections[0].replace("[[[","").replace("],  
[","").replace('""',"").split('"')


    co = -1
    for thing in secarray:
        if co %6 == 0:
            trans_string += thing
        co +=1
    print trans_string

def getReadableArticle(url):
    browse = mechanize.Browser()
    browse.set_handle_robots(False)
    browse.addheaders = [('User-agent'),('Firefox')]
    html = browse.open(url).read()

    readable_article = Document(html).summary()
    readable_title = Document(html).short_title()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(readable_article)
    final_article = soup.text

    links = soup.findAll('img', src = True)

    title_article = []
    title_article.append(final_article)
    title_article.append(readable_title)
    return title_article

def main():


    url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/01/13/sports/ncaafootball/ohio-state-upsets-  
oregon-and-wins-national-championship.html? 
hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top- 
news"

    article_attrs = getReadableArticle(url)
    readable_article = article_attrs[0]
    readable_title = article_attrs[1]

    chinese = translateString("en","zh-CN", str(readable_article))
    english = translateString("zh-CN","en",chinese)

    print readable_article[0:50]
    print chinese[0:50]
    print english[0:50]
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: just print out the value of browse.open(url).read() and you will know what to do.

Comment: it did the trick...bundle of thanks....I've commented functions one by one and solved one by one. You saved the day.

Comment: When you got an error,just print out or logging and see what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error info, browse.open(url).read() returns too many values, but you 
just give one value to hold them, so you got an error, like this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b,c = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So, print out the value of browse.open(url).read() and make sure the values number matched the length of function return before '=' will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

browse.open(url).read() did the trick. Thanks to @Zoosuck.